# Is it possible to create python virtual environment with ansible playbook?

Tags: python, vagrant, ansible, virtualenv

I have tried to create virtual environment in vagrant VM using ansible-local, but failed.

This is my Vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 4096
    v.cpus = 2
  end

  config.vm.define "shortener" do |shortener|
    shortener.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    # database 
    shortener.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 3307, guest: 3306
    # browser
    shortener.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 4568, guest: 4568
    shortener.vm.provision :ansible_local do |ansible|
        ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
    end
  end

  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

end
```

This is "playbook.yml":

```
- name: Deploy shortener
  hosts: all
  become: true
  become_method: sudo

  tasks:
    - name: Install packages
      apt: update_cache=yes name={{ item }} state=present
      with_items:
    - git
    - python-pip
    - nginx-full
    - vim
    - python-virtualenv
    - virtualenvwrapper
    - python3.4
    - python3.4-doc
    - python3.4-dev
    - software-properties-common
    - python-software-properties
    - postgresql
    - postgresql-client

- name: Load virtualenvwrapper
  shell: source /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper

- name:  Create virtual environment               
  shell: mkvirtualenv shortener --python=/usr/bin/python3

- name: Install requirements
  pip: requirements='/vagrant/configs/requirements.txt'
```

And this is the output of 'vagrant up':

```
hedin@home:~/url_shortener$ vagrant provision
==> shortener: Running provisioner: ansible_local...
    shortener: Running ansible-playbook...

PLAY [Deploy shortener]     
**************************

TASK [setup]
**************************
ok: [shortener]
**************************
TASK [Install packages]  
ok: [shortener] => (item=[u'git', u'python-pip', u'nginx-full', u'vim',   u'python-virtualenv', u'virtualenvwrapper', u'python3.4', u'python3.4-doc', u'python3.4-dev', u'software-properties-common', u'python-software-properties', u'postgresql', u'postgresql-client'])

TASK [Load virtualenvwrapper] 
**************************
fatal: [shortener]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "source  /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper", "delta": "0:00:00.003591", "end": "2016-09-23 16:06:43.169513", "failed": true, "rc": 127, "start": "2016-09-23 16:06:43.165922", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: source: not found", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT
**************************
[WARNING]: Could not create retry file 'playbook.retry'.  [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''


PLAY RECAP 
**************************
shortener                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

Also I tried to use '`command`' instead of '`shell`' with the same result.

I think I could use a shell script that creates virtualenvironment, but is it possible to fix that error with ansible means ?

Comment: The `pip` module supports a `virutalenv` parameter, so you shouldn't need to do this in a separate task ([docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/pip_module.html)).

Comment: I think the source of you problems might be when you source your python virtualenv :). Instead of sourcing the virtualenv, I usually use the full path of the ``python`` binary from the virtualenv in my playbooks. Maybe if you use the full path to ``mkvirtualenv`` it will work.

Comment: @notorious.no I am not sure what did you mean with "full path to mkvirtualenv", because it is just a function in "`virtualenvwrapper.sh`".

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. This is my "playbook.yml" file:

```
- name: Deploy shortener
  hosts: all
  remote_user: vagrant

 tasks:
    - name: Install packages
      become: true
      become_method: sudo        
      apt: update_cache=yes name={{ item }} state=present
      with_items:
        - git
        - python-pip
        - nginx-full
        - vim
        - python-virtualenv
        - virtualenvwrapper
        - python3.4
        - python3.4-doc
        - python3.4-dev
        - software-properties-common
        - python-software-properties
        - postgresql
        - postgresql-client

    - name: Install requirements
      become: true
      become_method: sudo        
      pip: 
        requirements: /vagrant/configs/requirements.txt
        virtualenv: /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/shortener
        virtualenv_python: python3.4
```

I have used standard pip module for that. Thanks for helpful comments!

Comment: Glad I could help.